# Fixing a coefficient on variable in MNL

Tags: r, mlogit

I have an MNL model with two alternatives with utility equations as follows:

```
U(1) = Beta*Toll1 + Gamma*Length1
U(2) = Beta*Toll2 + Gamma*Length2
```

I am trying to estimate the model using R MLOGIT package. I already know that the coefficient on toll should be -1 and so I want to fix Beta to -1. Is it possible to asset/fix a coefficient when estimating an MNL using MLOGIT.

Comment: Thanks! yes, my question seems to be the duplicate of the post you mentioned.